# get the next thursday relative to a particular date

Tags: php, date

I will like to get the next Thursday relative to a particular date if the date passed is not Thu. This is how far have gone with the code.

```
<?php 

$string = '2014.07.16';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y.m.d", $string);
$result = $date->format("D");
if ($result != 'Thu')
{
$result2 = strtotime('next Thursday');
echo date('Y.m.d', $result2);
}
?>
```

In the above code, the variable $string is the date passed which is a 'Wed'
I will like to get '2014.07.16' which is the next Thursday relative to '2014.07.17'. 
That means if $string is '2014.07.21' which is a Mon, the returned date will be '2014.07.24' that's the next Thursday relative to '2014.07.21' 
I am getting '2014.07.31' at the moment which is the next Thursday to today's date.

How do I get the next Thursday relative to $string (passed date)

Thank you.

Comment: $result !== 'Thu'  -> $result != 'Thu'

Comment: Try `$result = $date->format("W");`

Comment: Check your wording. _'2014.07.16' which is the next Thursday relative to '2014.07.16'_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$string = '2014.07.16';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y.m.d", $string);
$result = $date->format("D");
if ($result != 'Thu')
{
    $result2 = strtotime('next Thursday', strtotime($date->format("d-M-Y")));
    echo date('Y.m.d', $result2);
}
```

**OUPUT :** 2014.07.17

**[Working Demo](https://eval.in/171696)**

Answer (score 0):

strtotime is pretty smart and can work with all kind of parameters. However you need to pass the date in a different format than you are using. Just replace . with - before passing the date to strtotime:

```
$string = '2014.07.16';
$string = str_replace('.', '-', $string);

if (date('w', strtotime($string)) != 4) {
    $date = date('Y.m.d', strtotime($string . ' next thursday'));
    echo $date;
}
```

date('w') returns the day of the week as integer. It's nicer to use this for comparison than a string.

Comment: Thanks Peter, yours is a great one to consider as well.